# Change textlabel in static cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static UITableView, content of each cell I've made in storyboard, but I need to change texLabels of some cells programmatically while runtime. How can I do it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create a property for each cell you want to change in your table view controller, like so:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell1;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell2;
```

Connect each one to a cell in Interface Builder.

When you only need to change the label's text, you can use

```
self.cell1.textLabel.text = @"New Text";
```

If you need to replace the whole label, use

```
UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.cell2.textLabel = newLabel;
```

Comment: No, you must not retain all your cells, because you must reuse your cells, and not load all cells to the memory, you must have only the cells that you are showing loaded!

Comment: @ggrana Since these are static cells we're dealing with, there aren't likely to be that many of them, so the memory usage will not be that significant. However, I do agree that your edited answer is better than mine, so I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 10):

@RossPenman has posted a good answer.

@ggrana noted a potential issue to do with memory and cell reuse, **however don't worry about that** ...

For a `UITableView` with Static cells all the **cells are instantiated up front, before `viewDidLoad`** is called on your `UITableViewController` and aren't reused in the way that dynamic cells are. As such you can even just take `IBOutlets` directly to the `UITextFields`, `UISwitches`, `UILabels` and things you are really interested in that you have dropped into you static cells in the Storyboard.

Comment: I did not know you can create `IBOutlets` from static cells. Have to dig more into documentation, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I needed this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    (...textLabel updates)
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cell from your table view using the method cellForRowAtIndexPath, you will need to define a outlet that retrieves your tableview.

```
__weak IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

after that you can get the cell like that:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourRow inSection:yourSection];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Your new text"];
```

Maybe after setting the text you will need to adjust your label, or your cell height, if you want a deeper help provide more information, and I will be glad to help you.

And you are done, hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need to declare an Outlet to the tableView since you're already using a UITableViewController.

Comment: a UITableView configured with 'Static cells' can only exist in the context of a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

> **Swift  solution:**

First make a IBOutlet of static TableViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellFirst: UITableViewCell!
```

then in viewDidLoad change label Name.

```
cellFirst.textLabel?.text = "Language"
```

**Note:** If you have attached a label on TableViewCell then just hide it using storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!
private var yourText: String?
```

I just custom in this tableview's delegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let yourText = yourText else { return }
    yourTextField.text = yourText
}
```

When you change the text:

```
yourText = "New text here"
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for (int section = 0; section < [table numberOfSections]; section++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < [table numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
        NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        UITableViewCell* cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
        cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Your text";
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to keep your changes out of viewDidAppear and to place them in viewWillAppear or you will run into problems

Answer (score 0):

**Your can try it**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    cell.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
}
```